# Java CommandBuilder incomplete execution of copy command

Tags: java, windows, web-crawler

I built a web crawler that records a livestream. After the recording is finished, the individual *.ts files are to be merged into a video. Since after my research FFMPEG has only a complex procedure over a text file as input parameter, it seems to me clearly eifnacher to use the available functions of the operating system.

I can use `cmd.exe /c copy /b *.ts J:\final\output.mp4` 
to merge my ts files. However, as soon as I execute the command via the CommandBuilder, only the first 5 to 10 files are merged. So the video will be only a few seconds long. If I execute the command manually via Windows, all files are merged correctly.  How does this happen? My commandExecture method looks like this:

```
private int execCommand(String dirPath, String command) {

    try {
        String[] commandArr = command.split(" ");

        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commandArr);
        pb.directory(new File(dirPath));
        pb. redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process p = pb.start();


        return p.exitValue();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return -9999;
}
```

I suspected that the program exited before the command was fully executed. So I added the following after pb.start() :

```
        while(p.isAlive()) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
                System.out.println("running");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

also this did not change anything. How does this happen and how can I make it merge automatically?

Comment: Is this program is freezing - not reaching `p.exitValue()` line?

Comment: no, its passing